# TFEST Matlab How it works?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the transfer function of a DC Motor by Explicit Measurement. I have the voltage, output and time values.

I'm actually using the tfest function from matlab and it's accurate, but I’m wondering, what's the algorithm that they use to find the tf?

Any ideas? The web site says that they use the prediction error minimization (PEM) approach, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Thanks!

[image: Real Measurement VS TF Estimation]

Comment: have you tried `edit tfest`?

Comment: If you did a `edit tftest` yourself, you would see that if calls an internal function `_tftest`, which encapsulates all the estimation. The `tgest.m` does mainly variable/argument management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of instrument variable based and subspace (n4sid) estimation approaches are used to initialize the transfer function coefficients. The initialized coefficients are then passed on a nonlinear least squares solver to iteratively minimize the prediction error. Type "doc tfest" and browse to the Algorithm section for some more info.

See also: 
[1] Garnier, H., M. Mensler, and A. Richard. "Continuous-time Model Identification From Sampled Data: Implementation Issues and Performance Evaluation" International Journal of Control, 2003, Vol. 76, Issue 13, pp 1337–1357.

[2] Ljung, L. "Experiments With Identification of Continuous-Time Models." Proceedings of the 15th IFAC Symposium on System Identification. 2009.